# Large amount of traffic incoming. Preparation tips

Tags: apache-2.2, performance, traffic, load-testing

Looking for any tips on improving performance on the server level as my client will be getting some heavy traffic in the next few days.

Using a 1and1 cloud vps and increased the memory pretty high on the server. Is there anything I need to do to apache to make it start using those resources?

Comment: You might also consider offloading your static assets (JS, CSS, images) to a CDN like Amazon Cloudfront.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Apache Performance Tuning](http://www.devside.net/articles/apache-performance-tuning) (scroll past massive advertisement).